# How to combine two data.frames, using a row value to populate matching field value

Tags: r

I have two `data.frames` that I would like to join, but I can't find an answer on how to assign `largetree$TreeSpeciesCode` to the matching Project column name...

I tried this, which I knew would just add the columns to the data frame according to samplingeventno, but I'm unsure on how to assign the value in `largetree$freq` to `Project$ABBI` based on the the matching name in `largetree$TreeSpeciesCode`

```
project<-merge(project, largetree, by.x=c("SamplingEventNo"),by.y=c("SamplingEventNo"))




head(project)
  PlotNo ProjectNo District        ProjectName NaturalSubregion     PlotID SamplingEventNo ABBA ABBI ACGL ACNE ALTE BEPA LALA LALY LAOC PIAL PIBA
1      1         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM37073208               1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2      1         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM37073208              89   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3      2       158    Edson pb_MeadowlandCreek        Subalpine MC32894914               2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
4      2       158    Edson pb_MeadowlandCreek        Subalpine MC32894914             154   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
5      3         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM36723181             362   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6      3         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM36723181               3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA


> head(largetree)
   SamplingEventNo TreeSpeciesCode VegetationStatus freq
1               1            PIBA             Live   27
2               2            ABBA             Live    4
3               2            ABBI             Live   10
4               2            BEPA             Live    1
5               3            ABBI             Live    2
6               3            PIBA             Live    1
```

Desired Output

```
    head(project)
  PlotNo ProjectNo District        ProjectName NaturalSubregion     PlotID SamplingEventNo ABBA ABBI ACGL ACNE ALTE BEPA LALA LALY LAOC PIAL PIBA
1      1         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM37073208               1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   27
2      1         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM37073208               2   4   10   NA   NA   NA   1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3      2       158    Edson pb_MeadowlandCreek        Subalpine MC32894914               3   NA   2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   1
4      2       158    Edson pb_MeadowlandCreek        Subalpine MC32894914               4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
5      3         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM36723181               5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6      3         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM36723181               6   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Any help would be awesome!  Thanks so much, Kevin

Comment: let me go ahead and fix that.  My apologizes @cuttlefish44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my kind of classic, very sluggish, but steady method (If your `nrow(data)` < 10000, this method has enough speed to do it).

```
project2 <- project  # backup
largetree[,2] <- as.character(largetree[,2])

invisible(sapply(1:nrow(largetree),     # update
  function(x) project[match(largetree[x,1], project$SamplingEventNo), largetree[x,2]] <<- largetree[x,4]))
project <- project[order(project$SamplingEventNo),]
project
```

Answer (score 1):

If we use the `tidyverse` framework, this is accomplished by *converting* you data into "tidy" data and then performing a simple left join.

For instance:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

project.text <- "PlotNo ProjectNo   District    ProjectName NaturalSubregion    PlotID  SamplingEventNo ABBA    ABBI    ACGL    ACNE    ALTE    BEPA    LALA    LALY    LAOC    PIAL    PIBA
1   7   Calgary pb_SaddleMountain   Montane SM37073208  1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
1   7   Calgary pb_SaddleMountain   Montane SM37073208  89  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2   158 Edson   pb_MeadowlandCreek  Subalpine   MC32894914  2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2   158 Edson   pb_MeadowlandCreek  Subalpine   MC32894914  154 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3   7   Calgary pb_SaddleMountain   Montane SM36723181  362 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3   7   Calgary pb_SaddleMountain   Montane SM36723181  3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA"

largetree.text <- "SamplingEventNo  TreeSpeciesCode VegetationStatus    freq
1   PIBA    Live    27
2   ABBA    Live    4
2   ABBI    Live    10
2   BEPA    Live    1
3   ABBI    Live    2
3   PIBA    Live    1"

project <- read_tsv(project.text)
largetree <- read_tsv(largetree.text)

project %>%
  # Collect the columns into a "tidy" row format
  gather(key, value, ABBA:PIBA) %>%
  # Remove the values, since we're over-writing with largetree
  select(-value) ->
  project.tidy
```

That allows us to do this:

```
head(project.tidy)

# A tibble: 6 × 8
  PlotNo ProjectNo District        ProjectName NaturalSubregion     PlotID SamplingEventNo   key
   <int>     <int>    <chr>              <chr>            <chr>      <chr>           <int> <chr>
1      1         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM37073208               1  ABBA
2      1         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM37073208              89  ABBA
3      2       158    Edson pb_MeadowlandCreek        Subalpine MC32894914               2  ABBA
4      2       158    Edson pb_MeadowlandCreek        Subalpine MC32894914             154  ABBA
5      3         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM36723181             362  ABBA
6      3         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM36723181               3  ABBA
```

Note that the "key" column (which we created) is repeated.

Given that, we can just join -

```
project.tidy %>%
  left_join(largetree, by = c("key" = "TreeSpeciesCode", "SamplingEventNo")) %>%
  # Remove extraneous column
  select(-VegetationStatus) %>%
  # Spread back out
  spread(key, freq) ->
  output
```

And so we're done:

```
head(output)

  PlotNo ProjectNo District        ProjectName NaturalSubregion     PlotID SamplingEventNo ABBA ABBI ACGL  ACNE ALTE BEPA LALA LALY LAOC PIAL PIBA
1      1         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM37073208               1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   27
2      1         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM37073208              89   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3      2       158    Edson pb_MeadowlandCreek        Subalpine MC32894914               2    4   10   NA   NA   NA    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
4      2       158    Edson pb_MeadowlandCreek        Subalpine MC32894914             154   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
5      3         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM36723181               3   NA    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1
6      3         7  Calgary  pb_SaddleMountain          Montane SM36723181             362   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```